# Unzip a folder which is programatically downloaded in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

My requirement is this. I am programmatically downloading a folder from a remote server in zipped format using WebClient. This part is done. My folder will have only DLLs and EXEs. Can any one suggest an unzipping algorithim or libraries which can be used for unzipping?

http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/04/21/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight.aspx

I tried out the method suggested in the above link. But my DLLs and EXEs are getting corrupted. Can any one help me out in this?

My programming environment is VS2010 and Silverlight 4.0. Application is OOB and has Elevated Priv

Comment: Are you creating an OOB with elevated privs?

Comment: Yes , I am creating an OOB with elevated privs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a console/shell command to unzip the file.

Or Use this
[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)